# Fetch data from database in MYSQL/PHP using array

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch the data from database which is equal to post value which is in array.

```
For eg:$totv=$Post['Totv']  //where Totv is an array.

    Sql Query:SELECT Wo_Qty
    FROM Work_order
    WHERE B_Name IN (".implode(',', $totv)." )"; 
      $result1=mysql_query($sql1,$con);
     while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
     {

     echo $row1['Wo_Qty'];
    }


             Table:Work_order
    Input:    B_Name=1,2,3,4   
             Wo_Qty=50,25,22,55          
             totv=1
    output:50.
```

I tried but I am facing an error.

```
Error:Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\AGP\forms\inv_rep.php on line 63
```

Please help me out.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do not use mysql_ . They are removed in php7.

Comment: share the actual code - this is a mess

Comment: If this is your actual code no wonder it's not working. Do please google how to do DB interactions with php.

Comment: @EpodaxPlease tell how to write a code hopefully you know what I want.

Comment: @Drudge.Thanks to share, I know mysql should not use but I had no choice.

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service, you're suppose to learn by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear and badly formatted but it appears the error lies in the use ( or rather, miuse ) of quotes in the sql - assuming that the entire sql statement is quoted with double quotes and the values derived from `implode` are within single quotes then you need to do something akin to the following, though as noted `mysql_*` methods are deprecated and should no longer be used.

```
if( !empty( $totv ) ){
    $sql="SELECT `Wo_Qty`
            FROM `Work_order`
            WHERE `B_Name` IN ('" . implode( "','", $totv )."' );";

    $res=mysql_query( $sql,$con );
    while( $rs=mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ) echo $rs['Wo_Qty'];
}
```

Comment: I understand that it's up to each user to decide whether they want to answer a question or not, but I urge you not to answer questions like these because they are off-topic and only continue to make people believe that they can ask whatever questions they want regardless of the rule set of SO. - Also, code only answers are hardly useful for anyone but provide OP with a quick fix.

Comment: You are probably correct in what you say @Epodax - but when you look at it you can see the error. Perhaps I should add some explanation too.